# WPF ProgressBar not shrinking to fit content when IsIndeterminate = true

Tags: c#, wpf, shrink

Ive got a simple `StackPanel` which contains a `TextBlock` and `ProgressBar`.

On startup, the width of the `ProgressBar` is perfect - it has sized itself to fit in its boundaries (stretched to '150' by it's sibling `TextBlock`).

However, when the `TextBlock` has stretched to a width further than 150 due to additional Text (which the `ProgressBar` nicely expands to fill the extra area), and is then shrunk, due to the removal of it's Text, the Width of the progress bar remains.

This only happens when `IsIndeterminate = true`

[image]

The following hastily put together code will show the workings;

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock MinWidth="150" Name="tb"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
       <ProgressBar MinHeight="20" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            tb.Text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        });
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            tb.Text = "A";
        });
    }).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the `Width` of the Progressbar to the `ActualWidth` of the `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock MinWidth="150" Name="tb"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
<ProgressBar MinHeight="20" IsIndeterminate="True" 
    Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=tb, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```